# Rooting HTC Desire 826W

Tags: rooting, htc-desire-816-dual

I tried to root my HTC desire 826W but it's not working . I couldn't get the token. When I boot my phone into bootloader it loads to hboot but when I try to enter fastboot or recovery it enters into a white screen and returns to hboot. When I press the power button again, it reboots. When i press Volume up, I can only navigate using Volume down. This is really frustrating, I would appreciate if anyone could help. The security is on i.e S-ON

Answer (score 0):

To Root Your HTC Desire 826 :

- Downloads the following files

Here’s link to download  [TWRP Recovery] and SuperSu from Below Link.

- Unlock your BootLoader from [this tutorial](http://phonehorn.com/2014/10/unlock-bootloader-htc-devices/)
- Transfer the downloaded SuperSU.zip to root of device memory after downloading and the proceed to next step.
- If device is on press Volume Down and Power Key together for about 10-seconds and device will turn off. At this point leave power key but keep holding volume down and you will enter to fastboot mode.
- Connect Phone to PC using data cable. Extract files from Recovery.rar in one location and simply click on recovery.bat.  Press Enter and It will start pushing TWRP to your device and within few seconds it will show as finished.

Note: In case auto flashing script doesn’t work on your PC, open TWRP folder extracted from Recovery.zip file.

- Hold Shift Key and Right Click on Mouse… Then click on Open Command window here….
- Type this command -> `fastboot flash recovery TWRP_Recovery.img` and hit Enter.
- Disconnect phone and using volume keys select recovery option and reboot to recovery and install SuperSu.zip by selecting Install zip > and selecting supersu.zip transferred in third step to obtain root privilege.
- After successfully flashing the SuperSU reboot to system and congratulation now you have proper root access on your HTC Desire 826.

**Taken Source :** [Guide on How To Root HTC Desire 826 Quick and Easy](http://phonehorn.com/2015/05/guide-on-how-to-root-htc-desire-826-quick-and-easy/)

Comment: i have tried that method but always  im stock at fastboot with no token generated